# Pushing to S3 bucket

Tags: file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, federated-identity

How can I upload file directly to S3 using curl

My current flow is:

1. Service A makes a request to my application with a file name
2. My appln generates an S3 federated user and returns the client the session, access key and security key
3. Now the service A will directly upload the file to S3 bucket with the session details. This has to be done with curl library
4. Finally notify once S3 once upload is completed.

I am yet to identify how the step 3 need to be implemented. I have given CreateObject permission the federated user. But the upload is failing. I am trying to make the service run independent of the logic I am running behind and without knowledge

Any help will be appreciated. Looks like a silly mistake i am doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of error do you receive (take a look at downloaded file) ? Most likely you incorrectly sign outgoing request. Please take a look at this document: [Signing and Authenticating REST Requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html).

I would also recommend you to carefully read [Amazon S3 REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html) to understand how you should operate with S3 buckets / objects.

Hope it helps you !

Comment: I m getting permission denied. And more specifically, I need to know abt the rest based S3 API using federated user

Comment: It was improper token usages. COrrected it with the help of the docs.